# Missing ADO.NET data source for sqlite in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, sqlite, ado.net-entity-data-model

I've looked at other older threads on this and none of the answers have helped me. I'm using Visual Studio 2015. I grabbed the latest sqlite 1.0.97.0 and Entity Framework 6.1.3 and the ADO Data source is not listed as a option for the ADO.NET Entity Data Model. I've tried a few different versions of both entity framework and sqlite. I also tried a few versions of the .net framework (4.5 and 4.5.1) - Curious if anyone has any suggestions or has seen this.

Comment: In case someone encounter this problem, refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50730017/9893519

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wait for version 1,0,98, due next week https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/news.wiki

Comment: Thanks, I'd gone back to 2013 but I didn't really want to, this is good news, much appreciated.

Comment: It seems that version 1.0.99 (downloaded from https://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.99.0/sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.99.0.exe) makes the ADO .NET Entity Data Model option disappear in Visual Studio 2015. Is this a regression?

Answer (score 2):

Links to exact version getting outdated everytime. So instead of trying direct download link go here
https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki
(pretty messy) and find string below on page

---

This is the only setup package that is capable of installing the design-time components for Visual Studio 2015.

---

You need to download this one.
also, you can change VS version in your search string.

Answer (score 1):

I had to install this:
http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.101.0/sqlite-netFx46-setup-bundle-x86-2015-1.0.101.0.exe

Then i was able to select sqlite data source in VS 2015

Link to the last releases is here 
https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki