# How to connect to Sqlite in Visual Studio and create database?

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, c#-4.0

I can not find any way to connect to Sqlite in Visual Studio(Winform project).

I have installed libraries Sqlite using Nget manager.

In data source(left sidebar) I can not see connection to Sqlite, only SQL:

[image: Sqlite references]

[image]

Should I install a Slite database on the user's computer or the database will be built into the .exe program?

I tried to create database using SqliteMaestro, it saved databse file in program directory without extension as `database`. May I add this file to solution C#?

Answer (score 15):

In case somebody had the same issue. You may need to install [SQLite Data Provider](http://system.data.sqlite.org) by downloading the suitable version from [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki).

Check [SQLite/SQL Server Compact Toolbox](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.SQLServerCompactSQLiteToolbox), it is a great tool  to manage SQLite databases in Visual Studio (like SQL Server Explorer).

[image]

Comment: Youtube tutorial is no longer active.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've removed that section.

Answer (score 1):

ADO.NET 2.0 Provider for SQLite has over 200 downloads every day, so I think you should use that one.

Go and download it and after that you should be able to connect to a sqlite database from your Visual Studio.

Sometimes Google is all you need..

[ALSO CHECK FOR THIS LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GLCtoHagrtE)

Comment: Can I install this using Nuget? Should I install a Slite database on the user's computer or the database will be built into the .exe program?

Comment: @ITMANAGER What do you mean user's computer, it depends, if user is gonna connect to some remote sqllite database than you don't need because there will be defined connection string in your database and that's all you need to connect to a database, if it's going to be a local database than you should.

Comment: I mean when compiled program will be run in another computer. Can I create database in VS?

Comment: Last question, I try to connect to db as: `dbConnection = "Data Source=tests.DB;Password=;";`. But file is located by path: `debug/Tests.db` in project folder. How to specify full path?

Answer (score 1):

Windows version? SQLite support is now default on Windows 10.  Have you tried the ODBC DSN under Settings?